# Can I have different partitioners in a multiple datacenter configuration in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, partitioner

Can I have RandomPartitioner in the cluster in datacenter1 and Murmur3Partitioner in the cluster in datacenter2?

Comment: One more input - if you plan to upgrade from Cassandra 1.0.x to C1.2.x or later, you need to use RandomPartitioner only, you cannot user Murmur3Partitioner on the upgraded cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you need to have the same partitioner on all nodes in the cluster.

If you are asking this because you want a way of migrating from RandomPartitioner to Murmur3Partitioner then it won't work unfortunately.  I don't know of a method of moving to Murmur3Partitioner  on a live cluster, but the benefit is small so it is unlikely to be worth doing.

Comment: Even if they are 2 clusters on different datacenters? I know what you say is true in a single datacenter deployment, but I am specifically asking in a multi datacenter deploy. Also, the new datacenter starts empty.

Comment: The partitioner still needs to be the same. Every node needs to be able to compute the replicas for any key, regardless of which data center. This only works if all nodes use the same partitioner. Why do you want mixed partitioners?

Comment: Just because the new recommended one is Murmur, and I plan on decommissioning the original cluster when the new one is fully bootstrapped. I guess I'll have to live with the RandomPartitioner then.